# Get previous text of a div using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I've a set of divisions and I want to find the text previous to that particular div having class 'item-devider'. Finding the text of all specified  tag is not getting using JQuery.

### HTML

```
<small>
    Size: M<div class="item-devider"></div> 
    checkbox_test: Yes<div class="item-devider"></div>
    I don't mind about color: Yes<div class="item-devider"></div> 
    test: No<div class="item-devider"></div> 
    test_group: select1<div class="item-devider"></div>
</small>
```

### My code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    alert($('.item-devider').previous().nodeValue);

});
```

My fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/1128/.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.item-devider').map(function(){
    alert( this.previousSibling.nodeValue);
});
```

Comment: Exactly I did it and got it. :) Thanks Sajjad.

Answer (score 0):

Got it with the solution

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var texts = $('.item-devider').map(function(){
    alert(this.previousSibling.nodeValue);        

});
```

})